# How to get filename to from controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

After I uploaded file using file uplaod control, and assigning it's name in controller, i need to get that file name in view. Also with that file name how to delete that file in my local drive(which is previously uploaded).

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check it please

```
 public ActionResult SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
        {             
                string path = string.Empty;
                if (FileUpload != null)
                    if (FileUpload.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName);
                        path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Documents"), fileName);
                        FileUpload.SaveAs(path);
                    }                 

                return View();            
        }
```

and don't forget to add  **enctype = "multipart/form-data"**  attribute to form

to can use this jQuery plugin to upload file via ajax [jQuery File Upload in ASP.NET MVC](http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/)

Comment: yeah, thanks for that , it works fine .  But If i call the above SaveFile, through ajax from my view like $.ajax({ type:"POST", url:"/SaveFile"});  I'm getting  httppostfilebase null. can anyone have solution.

Comment: look here http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/